# Jacob (Java / COM / ActiveX) Throws ComFailException

Tags: java, dll, com, activex, jacob

I am using Jacob a Java-COM bridge and I have placed the required dll to -`C:\WINDOWS\system32\jacob-1.14.3-x86.dll`. I have also added the required jar file to - 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\lib\ext\jacob-1.14.3.jar`.

Until yesterday I was able to use it, today I uninstalled some unrequired .Net softwares on my machine and suddenly it stopped working and throws following error -

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:101)
at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
```

My machine belongs to "x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 3". I have tried to de-register/register the dll using regsvr32.exe but to no luck. I have no idea how to bring it to work again..other wise I will have to format my machine..geeks pls hlp me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if anyone faced similar problem by any chance.. 
Anyways I had no other option than to restore my machine to last working date.
I guess some JAVA-COM class entries would have been accidently deleted from the registry.
Had no idea which was it exactly..
Finally "System Restore" was my solution :)